# Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, ipad, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

In my application, i have a `navigation controller`. I have added a back button to go to the login screen `(UIViewController)`. How do i go back to the login screen from the `navigation controller`?

This is the code for my back button.

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(goBacktoLogin)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;

}

(void) goBacktoLogin

{

    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[ LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];

[[ self navigationController] popToViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];


}
```

I am getting the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>
> reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'

Comment: Is the login view always the first one and can you have more navigation levels?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to go back to the very first view controller in your navigation hierarchy, then use:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me. But I think this could help:

Push login controller in to the navigation stack using this,

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[ LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];

self.navigationController pushViewController:loginViewController animated:NO];
```

and in the pushed screen(login view controller):

push another controller.  Then add a back button. on click of it

execute this command:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```